# Blue background appears in the sign

Tags: support, comments

When some users write a comment, why there's a blue background on their sign at the end of the comment?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot may be useful here

Comment: screenshot added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They asked the question. Example:

> [image: Screenshot]